# Span banner image across width of browser window

Tags: javascript, html

**So Far:**
The image is shown on the browser, but it is not resized.

```
<html>

<img id="banner" src="c:/Users/Name/Downloads/picture.jpg" alt="banner" />


<Script>

var X = screen.width;
var Y = screen.height;

banner = document.getElementById('banner');
banner.style.width = X + 'px';
banner.style.height = (Y/5) + 'px';


</Script>

</html>
```

**Other Attempts:**

Show the image using purely javascript

- Width and height variables accessed through javascript

First, try with no size specs

- Image is not shown when I use:

  ```
  document.write("<img src='c:/Users/Name/Downloads/picture.jpg' />")
  ```

**Future Thoughts:**

My next attempt will be trying to pass the javascript width and height variables to the html since it seems that the html image always shows and given the right size specifications, then that would be exactly what I want. I will post that here if I find a successful method.

Comment: Why don't you use CSS to style it to take up the width of the browser, instead of using Javascript?

Comment: It's working... [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9mxTU/)

Comment: @akinuri Thanks for that link. I believe I had something slightly incorrect in the syntax. However, it only works with urls. When I try to use a personal file it produces a blank box. But the container for the image is there and the right size.

Comment: @MattClendenen You're using absolute path. That'll cause problems if you move the image file. Try moving the image file into the same folder where your html file is and use `src="picture.jpg"`.

Answer (score 0):

markup and CSS like this should do trick for you.

```
<div class="banner"></div>

div
{
    background:url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png) no-repeat left top;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Or even better you can try this CSS instead of above

```
div
{
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    top:0;
    height:250px;
    background:url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```